# UI change in app after xCode 9 iOS 11

Tags: ios, ios11, xcode9

I found my app changed UI after I updated xCode to 9.

See the image with post, Fonts look bigger, views look bigger, images lost crispness.

I'm facing this issue in iPhone 6 and later these issue, iPhone SE and and 5S looks fine the same.

Did anyone face this issue??

[image: Before updating xCode]

[image: After updating xCode]

Comment: did it work well i with iPhone 6 in xcode 8?

Comment: yes it did, app's first version was launched 2 years ago and had many updates, almost once every 2 month if not more. suddenly this happened...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got issue resolved.

We had started app with iOS 7, since then we have been using launch images set. we had never used Launch screen xib or storyboard....after adding launch screen xib everything's working fine now :)